# Ember view inside Bootstrap Popover

Tags: binding, view, ember.js, popover

I've been trying to get an Ember View as the content of a Boostrap popover where I can keep the bindings updating.

I was able to achieve this, you can check an example on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/331/).

Unfortunately this solutions causes an irregular popover placement.

Can someone please check my code and see what I did wrong or if there's a simpler way to achieve this?

```
  $popover.popover({
        html: true,
        placement:'bottom',
        content: function(){

            if(_this.get('childView')) {
                _this.get('childView').remove(); 
            }

            var view = _this.container.lookup('view:popoverContent'),
                childView = _this.createChildView(view),
                popover = $popover.data('popover'),
                $tip = popover.tip(),
                $content = $tip.find('.popover-content');

            _this.set('childView', childView);
            childView.appendTo($content);

            var html = $content.html();

            return html;            
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you just concerned about where it displays the popover? If that's the case I'd just add some css

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Found this, but didn't really solve my issue. https://coderwall.com/p/6gonpw - did you find a solution? Thks

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean with

> Unfortunately this solutions causes an irregular popover placement.

is that you want your popover's to show always with the same placement. If I guessed right, the only thing what I'm seeing missing in the jsfiddle you provided is that from the two popover's only one has set it's `placement` property to `bottom`, the second one is using the default which is `right`.

So the solution here might be to define always the same `placement` property for all popover's you use. As stated in the [docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) the `placement` can be one of these values as a string:

```
top | bottom | left | right
```

I've updated the jsfiddle to show up always on the right, have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/334/). For any custom placements you should dig into the responsible css for the popover's and override there what you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @intuitivepixel. But unfortunately, I forgot the bottom placement there because I was trying to do that already. But if you notice, although the placement is 'right' it still shows a little bellow the anchor tag.